# Why does this code not print the characters backwards

Tags: python

```
def anti_vowel(text):
    p=''
    for c in text:
        if c=='a' or c=='A':
            break
        elif c=='e' or c=='E':
            break
        elif c=='i' or c=='I':
            break
        elif c=='o' or c=='O':
            break

        elif c=='u' or c=='U':
            break
        else:
            p=p+c



print(anti_vowel('Hello you'))
```

Comment: def anti_vowel(text):
    p=''
    for c in text:
        if c=='a' or c=='A':
            break
        elif c=='e' or c=='E':
            break
        elif c=='i' or c=='I':
            break
        elif c=='o' or c=='O':
            break
        
        elif c=='u' or c=='U':
            break
        else:
            p=p+c
    

                
print(anti_vowel('Hello you'))

Comment: You are not returning anything, the function needs a return, probably `p`

Comment: I have a feeling that you want to use `continue` instead of `break`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to *return* `p` at the end of your function:

```
def anti_vowel(text):
    p=''
    for c in text:
        if c=='a' or c=='A':
            break
        elif c=='e' or c=='E':
            break
        elif c=='i' or c=='I':
            break
        elif c=='o' or c=='O':
            break
        elif c=='u' or c=='U':
            break
        else:
            p=p+c
    return p
```

Without that last line all you'll ever print is `None`, the default return value for functions without an explicit `return` statement.

Of course, your function will only ever print the first consonants, as `break` *ends* the loop as soon as you find any vowels. It'll not reverse the string, ever. For your sample input, the function return `'H'`, because the next letter in the input is a vowel, and `break` then ends the loop.

You could easily re-write your function to use `str.lower()` and a containment test:

```
def anti_vowel(text):
    p = ''
    for c in text:
        if c.lower() in 'aeiou':
            break
        p += c
    return p
```

This does the same thing, return the first consonants (`'H'` for your sample input).

If you wanted to *reverse* letters, *and* exclude vowels, don't use `break` and invert where you place the remaining letters. You could use `continue` instead, or more simply, just invert the `if` test and only process a chararter if it is **not** a vowel:

```
def anti_vowel(text):
    p = ''
    for c in text:
        if c.lower() not in 'aeiou':
            p = c + p
    return p
```

Now consonants are placed **before** any preceding consonants, reversing the text:

```
>>> def anti_vowel(text):
...     p = ''
...     for c in text:
...         if c.lower() not in 'aeiou':
...             p = c + p
...     return p
... 
>>> anti_vowel('Hello you')
'y llH'
```